# character escapes in path name cause mercurial confusion

Tags: macos, mercurial, osx-mavericks

Top directory keeps appearing in `hg status` as untracked.

```
? .
```

`hg add .` returns strange result:

```
adding .
abort: '\n' and '\r' disallowed in filenames: '.\r'
```

`hg verify` states no problem:

```
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
7044 files, 8094 changesets, 50081 total revisions
```

Other clones from same repository does not exhibit this behavior. I tried both hg 3.0.1 and 2.7.2. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you actually have a file whose name is a single dot followed by a carriage return.  Notice: `disallowed in filenames: '.\r'`

Here's me simulating that:

```
$ hg init Thomas
$ cd Thomas/
$ echo -e '.\r'
.
$ touch $(echo -e '.\r')
$ ls -A
.?  .hg/
$ hg status
? .
$ hg add .
adding .
abort: '\n' and '\r' disallowed in filenames: '.\r'
```

You've got a file whose name is a really bad idea, and it wasn't created by Mercurial.

Comment: I have successfuly deleted the offending file with `rm $(echo -e '.\r')`. Thank you.